# How can I overide a build function with flutter Mixins

Tags: flutter, flutter-module

When I try to attach a mixin to a flutter state, I want to overide the build function of the state like what we do in widget inheritence, however, every time when I tried to do so. it gives me an error.

Is there any one know how to override a state's build function in Mixins? Or is it actually not allowed? If it is not allowed, then why?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `class FooWithMixin extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FooWithMixinState createState() => _FooWithMixinState();
}

class _FooWithMixinState extends State<FooWithMixin> with FooMixin {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
children: [
super.build(context),
Text('from state'),
],
);
}
}

class FooMixin {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Text('from mixin');
}
}`

Comment: sure, your welcome, but actually why dont you want to extend `State` class and use it as a base class for other `State` classes?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't actually fully understand what you mean here, do you mean extend the state with the foo function and use that state for the stateful widget?

Comment: AH yeah, I get your idea, the reason why I don't want to use that is probably because of the collaboration, I want the other developers to simply call a with a do all the job rather than go through inheritence.

Comment: actually man, what i am confused here is why mixin is called in the super function, why it is not the abstract class call the build function as super in mixin. Thank you

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean